# Talking to a scanner from a PHP script

Tags: php, scanning

I run a small business but I need to be somewhat more organised in terms of those letters and invoices i receive. This is what I want to accomplish:

1. When I receive a invoice or some other information on paper, I would place it in my scanners tray and leave it there.
2. Every 15 minutes my linux box ask my scanner if there is anything to scan and if so starts the scanning process and place the file in a folder.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to how I can talk to my scanner from a PHP-script, like "Are there anything to scan ?" and "Start scanning, place the file here"...

Comment: Does your scanner actually have a function to see if there are items to be scanned? If the hardware doesn't support it then no amount of software will :)

Comment: Good point. If it does not I could just start the scanning process and tjeck if the images is all white. That should solve the first part of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's [phpSane](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsane/), a web frontend to your scanner. Internally it just `exec`'s the `scanimage` commandline tool though. That's what I would use if I were you. `scanimage` is only available on Linux though.